# Serilog overwrite file

Tags: .net, serilog

How does one configure Serilog so it overwrites the file every time the program executes?

---

**Code**

```
   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
      .MinimumLevel.Debug()
      .WriteTo.ColoredConsole()
      .WriteTo.File("c:\\Logs\\myapp.log")
      .CreateLogger();
```

It doesn't hurt to append the entry logs of the new execution but during development is convenient just getting the current ones.

Comment: Just manually clear it before creating the logger object? `#if debug System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\Logs\myapp.log",string.Empty); #endif`.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in the comment above, deleting the file with `System.IO.File.Delete()` is the way to go:

```
File.Delete("c:\\Logs\\myapp.log");
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is still an issue with deleting files (from the test itself) as
[seen in this issue](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/143)
I also had to delete the file but ended up simply cleaning it at the end of the test as suggested [in this thread's post](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/96#issuecomment-485098014)

**Another suggestion** is to do the same workaround as I did.

On your dispose method (or at the end of your test method, or wherever you need it)

```
public void Dispose() 
{
    // Some dispose code

    Serilog.Log.CloseAndFlush();
    File.Delete(LogFilePath);            
}
```